# TextFormField Landscape view fill the screen with keyboard in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, flutter-layout

I have a `TextFormField` in Flutter like this in landscape view
[image: Implemented TextField]

I want to make it like this one
[image: Desired TextField]

How I can do this in Flutter?

Comment: I don't think there is a "ready to use" solution for this. Flutter treats screen as a canvas and draw on it. One of the downsides of this is Texts and Form fields can't act like native apps on every platforms supported. You may think a custom solution here.

Comment: do you have any suggestion that i can use to achieve it?

Comment: You might try to show a Stack widget when Email Form Field selected. This Stack widget has a Text Field according to clicked Text Field (Email field)  and covers whole screen left from keyboard. You should also handle Next button and think about other native use cases. This latter Text Field must notify real field onChange events. It will get complicated.

Comment: that sure seems complicated, i will try search something else that might help me to do a similar things, thanks for your suggestion

Comment: Hi @karin, did u find a solution for this?

Comment: sadly no @SalahRashad, i just go with first image for now

Answer (score 0):

Flutter has yet to have this feature and here's an open [GitHub issue ticket](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/82999) that you can track. A close workaround would be to set `maxLines` and `keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline` on your TextFormField to allow the TextField to expand.